# how to prove function satisfy Lipschitz condition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1,\ldots, v_n\in \mathbb{F}_{2}^r$  be $n$ column vectors chosen uniformly and independently at random from ${\mathbb{F}_2}^r$. Let $f$ be a function defined as follows:$
[f(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$= $\min _{D\subseteq [n], \{v_i~|~i\in D\}\mbox{ are linearly dependent}}|D|, ]$
i.e., $f(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ is the minimum number of columns that are linearly dependent.
Show that $f$ satisfies the  Lipschitz property.

Comment: What are the metrics (and on exactly which spaces)? Are we considering $W:={(\Bbb F_2^r)}^n$ with metric $d((v_1,..,v_n)\,,\,(w_1,..,w_n)):=\sum_i d(v_i,w_i)$?

Comment: d is correct but it is W=$F_2^r$ :(

Comment: [Simultaneously cross-posted on cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/how-to-proove-the-function-contains-lipschitz).  **Don't do that.**

Answer (score 4):

As stated, $f$ is identically zero; the *smallest* linearly independent subset of *any* set of vectors is the empty set.  The zero function is trivially Lipschitz for every metric.